# Setup a logger that work as a tee command

Tags: python, logging, progress-bar, tqdm, tee

I want to setup a logger that work as a tee command. Essentially, I want to set up a logger that logs console outputs to a file while also displaying them in the console.

I pass the path of the log file `log_file_path` and it will log all the console outputs to that file while also showing the console outputs in the console. Beware I use TQDM in my code so it should handle their output as well. I want the exact output of the TQDM to be seen in the log file. Also, if possible I don't want the log file to have several lines for the same TQDM iteration.

I already have this:

```
import sys


class TeeLogger(object):
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files

    def write(self, obj):
        for file in self.files:
            file.write(obj)
            file.flush()

    def flush(self):
        for file in self.files:
            file.flush()


def setup_logger(log_file_path):
    log_file = open(log_file_path, 'w')
    sys.stdout = TeeLogger(sys.stdout, log_file)
```

However the tqdm output does not appear in the log file. I tried redirecting sys.sterr as well but that always breaks the tqdm output in the console. I would like the tqdm output to remain normal.